# How to remove a node from the seed list in Cassandra without lossing data?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is there the proper way of how to remove a node from the seed list in Cassandra's cluster? I just want to reduce the seeds list without actual replacing or decomission of a node. Is that possible?

Comment: Just curious why you want to remove/ reduce seed nodes ?

Comment: Since I added too much of them per cluster :) Actually every node in the cluster being a seed node before I ve made the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just remove the particular node from the seed list on all nodes, and either perform a rolling restart, or call `nodetool reloadseeds` (if you have version of Cassandra that has this subcommand - I don't remember in which version it was introduced...)

Answer (score 0):

Remove node ip/hostname from seed list from all nodes of Cassandra cluster and take a rolling restart of all nodes.